# ¿Por qué este script me devuelve "error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `$'do\r''"?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estoy tratando de lanzar el siguiente script en bash cuya finalidad es desproteger multiples ficheros pdf con qpdf.

```
#!/bin/bash
pdf="/var/www/"
pdfdest="/var/www/html"
cd $pdf
for f in *.pdf; do
    qpdf --decrypt $f $pdf $pdfdest/$f
done
```

Sin embargo, me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> # bash /var/www/decrypt.sh
> /var/www/decrypt.sh: línea 2: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `$'do\r''
> /var/www/decrypt.sh: línea 2: `for f in ./var/www/*.pdf; do
> ```

[image: error]

Comment: Un favor: procura añadir tu código y los mensajes de error como texto, no como imágenes. Reproducir tu script a partir de una imagen no facilita recibir ayuda.

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo, tomo nota y en un futuro lo pondré como texto, era mi primera entrada en este  foro. Un saludo

Comment: Aún estás a tiempo, @jrodherrera. Dale a [edit] y copia el contenido que habías puesto como imagen.

Comment: Parece que tienes un fichero de Windows y lo estás leyendo en Linux. Por ello, debes convertirlo con `dos2unix fichero`.

Comment: No te preocupes, estamos para ayudar :) PD. Bienvenido!

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente la sintaxis es correcta, pero por el `\r` que veo en el mensaje de error, ¿no será que has guardado el *script* en formato msdos, o sea, con los cambios de línea "\r\n"? Haz:

```
sed -ri 's:^M$::' nombre_script.sh
```

y vuelve a ejecutarlo. El `^M` no es `Ctrl+M`, sino `Ctrl+V Ctrl+M`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose Miguel, efectivamente por ahí iban los tiros. He utilizado el comando sed del siguiente modo: sed 's/.$//' miScript.sh   y ha funcionado, Un saludo y gracias a todos!!

Answer (score 0):

Solucion:

## sed 's/.$//' script.sh > newScript.sh

## bash newScript.sh

Gracias a Jose Miguel A 
Gracias Fedorqui

Comment: Ten cuidado con ese sed, porque elimina el último carácter siempre, sea el que sea. Como el script, realmente, no tenga formato msdos, te lo desbarata. El sed que te propuse yo, sólo eliminado el "\r" en caso de que exista.